# .load() not calling my php page in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to call a php page which essentially parses my xml and if there's changes in the xml, it inserts that data into a mysql table.

My code originally was:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('.blabla').load('parser.php');
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
```

where .blabla was an empty div and parser.php did not echo any information - I only called the php to check the xml.

Rather than call the php every 10 seconds which seems a bit unnecessary, I want to call the php before my page loads.

How would I go about doing that?

This is what I have got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.blabla').load('parser.php');

});
```

which is not working.

Comment: try to load on a id ,not a class,like #myid

Comment: that doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Why are you using `load()` if you're not inserting content? You should be using `$.get` or `$.ajax`, which load is a convinient shortcut for, that also inserts the content!

Comment: Run firebug and look in the console - what is happening?

Comment: okay, do you think it will be worth rescripting it using ajax?

Comment: console is showing that is has actually got the parser.php file but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason

Comment: It's not really rescripting when we are talking about two lines of code, here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XZP3y/)

Comment: When inside the interval, the first time the function runs is after the first ten seconds has passed. If it does'nt work outside the interval, something is needed that has'nt loaded yet, what that something is only you can know!

Comment: @AndrewCharlton show your html markup

Comment: I think it's the php - I've just refreshed the php and nothing is happening

Comment: .load() is technically ajax

Comment: @naspinski - You're right, but load automagically inserts the content returned in the ajax function. If the OP is'nt inserting content, there's no need for load().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.blabla').load('parser.php', function()
        {
            //just to see if you loaded the php 
            alert("loaded yay!");  
       });

    });
```

If there is no message, the problem maybe the php.

Comment: I get no alert - hmm why would it work when i had setinterval on it though?